# Gradle SpringBoot: Could not find main class

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

My gradle file contains:

```
  plugins {
       id 'java'
   }

  configurations {
       compileOnly {
           extendsFrom annotationProcessor
       }
  }

  jar {
      duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
      project.configurations.getByName("implementation").setCanBeResolved(true)
      manifest {
           attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication'
      }

      from { configurations.implementation.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
     }

    repositories {
       mavenLocal()
       gradlePluginPortal()
       mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
       implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.10'){
           exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
           exclude module: "logback-classic"
       }
   }
```

And Main SpringBoot class contains:

```
  package com.example.fileutil

  @SpringBootApplication
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.fileutil.service")
  public class FilePrepareApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
               SpringApplication.run(FilePrepareApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception { 
                   System.out.println("checkResult");
         }          
    }
```

After clean build, I run my application with:

```
   java -jar build/libs/file_util.jar -cp build/classes/java/main/ com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication
```

And receive the error:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication

Comment: Pretty abvious but just to be sure because it's not in your question: How does your package declaration in `FilePrepareApplication` look like?

Comment: package com.example.fileutil    I updated my code-snipped

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: I can't reproduce your error using the code provided. But for your case, better use gradle springboot plugin, take a look https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/